# Is it possible to import the content of a rich text field into matrix using FeedMe without parsing reference tags to entries/assets?

Tags: filter, plugin-feedme, reference-tags

Currently I have content that I’m trying to migrate from a single rich text field into a rich text field living in a Matrix content builder. Migrating most of the content is fine, but I would like to know if it’s possible to migrate the reference tags so that I keep the established relationships. I’m concerned with those entries that are rendered on export/import as `<a href="https://www.website.com/linkSection/entry-slug">` and not `<a href="{entry:341:url}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with the always helpful Andrew Welch of https://nystudio107.com, I realize now that the answer to this is `entry.myRichText.getRawContent()` to output the exact information needed.